# How to check if one is using a raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberrypi

Let us imagine that you are in a room with a black box; you turn the box on and find that you are met with a helpful terminal.

Is there a command that could allow one to decipher that in that black box is a raspberry pi?

Comment: Raspberry Pi is not Ubuntu so this question is off topic here. At a guess `lsb_release -a; uname -a` may give you a clue but you can always ask on the [Raspberry Pi Forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo lshw` will list all hardware available on that system and thus at least allow an educated guess as to whether the box contains a Raspberry Pi.

Anyway, if the system in that box is running Ubuntu, it won't be a Raspberry Pi, since [Ubuntu does not support its CPU](https://askubuntu.com/a/212347/215352).

Comment: The latest Raspberry Pi model 2 does in fact support a version of Ubuntu. It is not distributed by Canonical and appears to be a repackaged OS. More information [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-get-ubuntu-desktop-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/).

Comment: On my Raspbian system, there is no `lshw` command. Nor is there a `lsb_release`. So this will not be a conclusive procedure.