# Ubuntu Snappy for a development machine

Tags: development, ubuntu-core

So Ubuntu Snappy core is supposed to be super lightweight. I was thinking to put that on a server, ssh to it and use it to write code. 
Would that work? Does it come with desktop environment? Can I install regular old packages via apt-get or am I limited to docker apps?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your interest into Ubuntu Core!

Ubuntu Core is really a small set of an Ubuntu system, as you said, lightweight. It doesn't come by default with a desktop environment or with apt-get (use snappy instead!)

I really encourage you to get familiar with the documentation (https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/). I think I may duplicate this one to [What is Snappy Ubuntu Core?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605066/what-is-snappy-ubuntu-core) which has better answers to your question.