# Why isn't sudo apt-get update an automatic thing?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

I just recently learned that `sudo apt-get update` only updates the list of packages to their most recent versions and doesn't actually install or update your software until you do `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Is there any reason why `apt-get update` is not some automatic thing? Would it make sense to include `sudo apt-get update` as part of an automatic startup script somehow so we don't have to manually do it before running what we really want (the upgrade)?

Comment: No, not really. Sometimes `apt-get` update fails (due to network problems, or similar) and **you want** to have the output. Moreover, using a user's network silently in the background is a very bad idea. Finally, soon we will move [to snappy packages](http://askubuntu.com/a/605087/29595), abandoning the old `apt-get` system.

Comment: Well, it sort of is. That popup that tells you when you have updates available is running `apt-get update` automatically. Open the Software & Updates app and you can change that schedule.

Comment: Just a quick note, `sudo apt-get upgrade` won't actually upgrade everything, to upgrade all things that need upgrading do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (though obviously this won't upgrade you to a new distribution - `sudo do-release-upgrade` will do that).

Comment: My point is - that's good too, but may not be user's desired behavior

Comment: @Serg: It upgrades packages to new release package versions? I thought it just handled kernel upgrades and more serious upgrades to the system... I don't think on 14.04 that it would get versions of packages which are for 15.10... Otherwise wouldn't that be the same as a `do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: @Serg: I think you are wrong and getting confused with `do-release-upgrade` because this is what the `apt-get` manpage says and it doesn't say anything you say about the `dist-upgrade` option:

Comment: `dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
           also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
           of packages;`

Comment: `apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
           it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
           expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade
           command may therefore remove some packages. The
           /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of locations from which
           to retrieve desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5) for
           a mechanism for overriding the general settings for individual
           packages.`

Comment: @ParanoidPanda yes, you're right. I did confuse it with do-release-upgrade. My bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically speaking, the GUI version of `apt-get update` does it automatically already - those already cater to the needs of a desktop user. Command line tools   are more of a technical type of user, typically admins , who know what they're doing.

However, there's nothing stopping you from making a script out of it, and reviewing logs every once in a while. For example, here's a quick sketch:

```
#!/bin/bash

main()
{
  local DATE=$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M)
  local LOGFILE=AUTO_UPDATE_$DATE
  local DIR="/home/localuser/logs" # where to store logs

  apt-get update &> "$DIR"/"$LOGFILE"
}

main
```

And use that as script to run upon [shutdown or reboot](https://askubuntu.com/q/293312/295286) using `/etc/rc6.d` directory scripts or alternatively - cronjob to schedule this script at specific time of day. Remember though that checking logs will be your responsibility.

In future, there will come `snappy` - a newer system for transactional updates which is now is in very young stage and supposedly should come to 16.04.  My experience with it is somewhat limited, but on Raspberry Pi it does update automatically and reboots itself once newer version of packages are available, sort of how Windows update works

**Addition**

Per muru's suggestion one could use [unattended-upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html) to automate the updates as well, and probably in a less verbose way than my solution.

Comment: Ideally, a person looking to automate this should use also `unattended-upgrades`

Comment: I think that's the best solution, muru. Forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just want to see what would be upgraded or what new packages are available for install. This is especially important if you are managing a server as upgrading some packages can cause problems. For a desktop user that doesn't care, the graphical software updater hides all this from you anyway.