# Snappy and Robotics

Tags: ubuntu-core

I am interesting in the Snappy environment for robotics development with the raspberry pi and other such hardware. I am very new at all of this, so what are the benefits of snappy in iOT versus, say, windows 10 sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You will find general answers about the net value of Ubuntu Core running in a snappy ubuntu core on the official website on both [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/snappy) and [this link](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/).

I would recommend as well this [askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605066/what-is-snappy-ubuntu-core?rq=1).

Note that snapcraft, the packaging tool to create snaps, has [a ROS plugin](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/ros-snap/) which should be useful for robotics development.