# What sudo apt purge snapd doing?

Tags: snap

What `sudo apt purge snapd` doing exactly and how to remove all `snap` apps from the system at once?

Comment: This looks like two separate questions. Apt's --purge flag is clearly explained in the dpkg documentation (see `man dpkg`). How to remove snap-provided applications is clearly explained in the snap documentation (see `man snap`).

Answer (score 2):

`snapd` is a daemon required to run snaps (see [What do snap, snapd and Snappy refer to?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963404/what-do-snap-snapd-and-snappy-refer-to)).

`sudo apt purge snapd` removes this software package AND associated configuration files.